# How to get a bit representation in C

Tags: c

I have a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float num = 3.4;
    unsigned int* bits = (unsigned int*)&num;

    for (int i = sizeof(float) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        unsigned int bit = (*bits >> i) & 1;
        printf("%u", bit);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

An I want to get a bit representation of **float**.
In this format:
[image]

But after compilation, I'm getting:

```
00000000000000001001100110011010
```

It looks like a sign and exponent are wrong. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float)` on your system?

Comment: Your sizeof(int) seems to be 16. Try `uint32_t` instead of `int`
by including <stdint.h>.

Comment: @tshiono It's unlikely that `sizeof (int)` is 16. That would be (at least) 128 bits, since `sizeof` yields the size in bytes. 16 *bits* is plausible, but only for a very small or very old system.

Comment: @KeithThompson or an old compiler like Turbo C on a modern system

Comment: Oh, my carelessness. I wanted to say the size may be 2.

Comment: Please add the sizes of `float` and `int`, the compiler, and the target system you use. Without that information we cannot help you really.

Comment: The size of int does not matter for this problem because int should not be used anyway.

Comment: @Lundin But the size of `int` matters if we want to explain the behavior of the code in the question. I'll also note that even if `float` and `unsigned int` have the same size, they might have different alignments, so `unsigned int* bits = (unsigned int*)&num;` could still have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Seems there's a mismatch between `int` and `float` sizes with the compiler/architecture you're using. (I tried your code and it worked fine for me; both `int` and `float` have size 4 octets here.)

You could cast `float` to a byte sized type and use a generic byte to bits converter instead. This way you would not have to worry about matching size of `float` with something else.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3208376/6874310) as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c"
#define BYTE_TO_BINARY(byte)  \
  ((byte) & 0x80 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x40 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x20 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x10 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x08 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x04 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x02 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x01 ? '1' : '0') 

int main()
{
    float num = 3.4;

    for (int i = sizeof (num); i > 0; i--) {

        printf(BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN,
               BYTE_TO_BINARY(((char*)&num)[i-1]));
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Leads to:

```
01000000010110011001100110011010
```